# Замена символа по индексу строки: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x

В Python-e я новичок.Непонятно почему нельзя обратиться к строке по индексу.

```
sequence[geneNumber] = 0
```

Пишет

```
'str' object doesn't support item assigment
```

Вот ссылка https://repl.it/Dojk/4

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в **самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В питоне строки - неизменяемый тип данных.
Вы можете из строки прочитать по индексу, но не можете заменить часть строки.

Можно только создать новую строку из старой и нового символа, и записать результат в ту же переменную.

То есть, так делать нельзя:

```
s[num] = new_simbol
```

А так можно:

```
s = s[:num] + new_simbol + s[num+1:]
```

Это верно и для двоичных строк (насколько я понял, в вашем коде используются именно они)

Comment: можно изменяемую последовательность использовать, такие как `list`, `mmap`, `bytearray`  или [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/)

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно заменить несколько символов можно сделать так:

```
str = 'aaaaa'
str_list = list(str)
for i in [1,3]:
    str_list[i] = 'b'    
str = ''.join(str_list)
# str = 'ababa'
```

Comment: мне кажется Вы не ответили на конкретный вопрос пользователя, а именно "можно ли обращаться к подстроке по индексу" и почему у пользователя возникла ошибка...по поводу первого еще можно догадаться исходя из Вашего ответа...но хотелось бы более явного предложения. А вот по поводу его ошибки Вы ему не ответили.